# ihave this error in a client server. why server try to disabled this php functions?

Tags: php

a host server try to disabled ignore_user_abort() function for security reasons. what usually the reason behind this action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its false by default.

`If changed to TRUE scripts will not be terminated after a client has aborted their connection.`

You can read about it at the [PHP manual.](http://au.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort)